# What are the differences between mlint and checkcode in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

MATLAB provides two functions to check code for errors `mlint` and `checkcode`.

What are the main differences between them, and why does the MATLAB help say that `mlint` is not recommended and `checkcode` should be used instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`checkcode` is just a new name for `mlint`.

About six or seven years ago, MathWorks decided that for reasons of brand and product integrity they would prefer it if people thought of MATLAB (including the language, the IDE, the graphics, the libraries etc) as a single entity called MATLAB, rather than separable things.

They realised that they had been contributing to the issue by referring (in code, comments, and some marketing material) to the underlying language as "M", which might give the impression that MATLAB was just a wrapper around the "M" language.

They went through the product and purged pretty much every reference to "M", and the `mlint` command was one of those cases.

However, they have many customers who rely on the existence of the command `mlint`, and wouldn't want to update their code. So `mlint` still exists for backward compatibility, but it's deliberately unadvertised, and its help/doc just says that it's no longer recommended, and that you should use `checkcode` instead.

In modern versions of MATLAB, if you type `edit mlint`, you'll see that it literally just calls `checkcode` under the hood.

The functionality is the same as it always has been, it's just a name change. Nevertheless, if you're starting a new project, you should use `checkcode`, as eventually all those legacy customers will have finally upgraded things, and at that point MathWorks may well decide to finally remove `mlint` entirely.